# error custome gridview in the fragment

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

i have an fragment that I want to show my custom gridview . gridview is working fine but when i put it in the fragment its force close . 
this is my code :

fragment :

```
public HomeFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,
            false);
    int[] icons = { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image5 };
    String[] names = { "asd ", "Asdasd", "asd " };

    CustomGrid grid = new CustomGrid(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), names, icons);
    GridView g = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    g.setAdapter(grid);
    return rootView;
}
```

it is my adb log when its force close :

```
    01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.tashrifat/com.plusnet.tashrifat.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at com.plusnet.tashrifat.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:28)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5142)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
01-04 08:30:22.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2379):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is going on inside the CustomGrid constructor?  Stay off the main UI thread.

Comment: in which layout `gridView1` Gridview present ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK in  'R.layout.fragment_home'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rootView` instead of `getActvity()` to initialize GridView because GridView is present in `fragment_home` layout which is current fragment layout:

```
GridView g = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
```